# What're the missing two words in the lyrics for "Die Young" by Ke$ha

Tags: lyrics

I need the 2 words to complete the lyrics for "Die Young", one of which is at 52 sec of the song, and the other at 2:07, both are in the beginning of sentences. I've seen the those irresponsible lyrics at azlyrics and metrolyrics, and they all read like:

0:52:

*`Let's make the most of the night like we're gonna die young
(fade in) Young hearts, out our minds`*

2:07:

*`Let's make the most of the night like we're gonna die young
(fade in) Young hunks, taking shots`*

Obviously the word before "*hearts*" or "*hunks*" is not "*young*", and this/these word(s) should have 2 syllables, at least that's how it sounds like to me.

I'm not planning on buying a CD just to check for the correct word, so if anyone happens to know what exact word(s) it is/they are, please simply tell me here. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The lyrics as transcribed in your question are correct.

The word "young" at the end of the last sentence is emphasized in a way that blends it into becoming the first word of the next line. The "fade in" you mention is just the prolonged singled word fading into the new context.

```
Let's make the most of the night like we're gonna die [young] hearts, out our minds
```

That aside, Google Play's lyrics should be accurate on the purchase page here: https://play.google.com/music/preview/T5m37seersrdxjg2dbxozkl5y3u?lyrics=1

Comment: I see how these lyrics want to make people think the last word and first word are overlapped, however, these are not the same word. If you listen to the song carefully, you will find that the first word at 0:52 is more like "beating" instead of "young", and "beating hearts" makes more sense if it really is. I'm just not sure about my guess, nor can I think of any word fitting in the one at 2:07.

Comment: Can you confirm that these are the song segments that you are referring to: https://soundcloud.com/xestrix/sets/music-fans-q3487 

Manipulating the above segments in Audacity in several ways has yet to visually or audibly reveal any second word being sung over or under the word "young".

Comment: Yes, these are what I refer to, and thanks for your patience. I think the vowel for the first word at 0:52 is more like an "ee"[i:] than an "oung"[ʌŋ].